# Writing an CSV file with html entities in it using Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, csv, firefox

I made this really simple csv file which I download from client site, here's the code :

```
var csv_file_content = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,";  
csv_file_content += "a,b&#39,c";

var uri = encodeURI(csv_file_content );  
var a = document.createElement("a");  
a.setAttribute("href", uri);  
a.setAttribute("download", "example.csv");  
document.body.appendChild(a);  
a.click();
```

In Chrome and IE I get all of the 3 cells (a, b&#39, c) but in Firefox I only get up to the "&" mark (a, b&), the rest is being omitted.
How can I make Firefox show the whole content?

Answer (score 0):

Try encodeURIComponent for line.

```
var csv_file_content = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,";  
csv_file_content += encodeURIComponent("a,b&#39,c");

var uri = csv_file_content;  
var a = document.createElement("a");  
a.setAttribute("href", uri);  
a.setAttribute("download", "example.csv");  
document.body.appendChild(a);  
a.click();
```